# Allure annotation @Step does not added into generated report

Tags: gradle, junit5, allure

When running tests, a report is generated, but the steps are not displayed and there is no information about the execution, in the "Execution" section it is written: "No information about test execution is available."
I think I have an error in configuring Gradle. But I don't know how to fix it. I tried to add the configuration specified in the Allure documentation, but it didn't help.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1'

    testImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.13.3'
    testImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.8.1'

    compile group: 'io.github.benas', name: 'random-beans', version: '3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```